# Maven war plugin overlays and eclipse

Tags: maven-plugin

I am using overlays for adding war dependencies. I have to exclude one jar from parent war lib before packaging war again. added excludes for overlays.

It works fine if I deploy the application using maven/Gradle script, But it fails as soon as I deploy from eclipse.

Reason: overlays unpack parent war in folder war/work and it has got all the lib. Eclipse is using this folder.

Is there any way I can fix this problem.